# Young Adult SciFi Book: Alien Web Used to Catch Asteroids, Cadet Saves Alien

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, soft-sci-fi

Looking for a paperback, science fiction story possible printed in the 70s-ish time frame, probably only 150 pages.  Seems to have been aimed at young adult / children as I enjoyed it in the 90s as a child.

Some major details:

- Young male protagonist as a cadet
- Believe the protagonist had a close male and female friend, both who are cadets.
- Had a pet alien that possible changed colour with mood, remember him a furry bug?
- Protagonist patrols near asteroid field finds metal filaments.
- He becomes attached to the filament that welds to his space suit, cuts himself free.
- Discovers alien 'spiders' that can shoot lasers (reminds me of the sentinel from Matrix)
- Human mining disturbs or injures the alien and its mate
- Aliens use metal filaments to catch asteroids to eat the metal from.

The cover for the print I had featured an action scene with the cadet in the asteroid field possible fleeing the 'spider' aliens.  Featured mostly blue, black and yellow colours.

Thank you.